# removing tweets with partial similarity

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, twitter, nlp

I am new to python and also to stackoverlfow. I have a csv file with three columns (ID, Date_Of_creation, Text). There are almost 25,000 entries in the file. I have to remove the duplicate tweets (text column) and the code below works fine to remove duplicates:

```
import csv

csvInputFile = open('inputFile.csv', 'r',encoding="utf-8", newline='')
csvOutputFile = open('outputFile.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline='')

csvReader = csv.reader(csvInputFile)
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvOutputFile)
cleanData = set()

for row in csvReader:
    #print(row[3])
    if row[3] in cleanData: continue
    cleanData.add(row[3])
    csvWriter.writerow(row)

print(cleanData)
csvOutputFile.close()
csvInputFile.close()
```

This code is removing all the duplicates with corresponding IDS and creation date.
As a second step of the analysis, i noticed that there are some retweets that don't have the original tweets in the data set. I want to keep those retweets.
In simple, i want to remove all the duplicates, whether its a tweet or retweet, from the Text column. For Example:

> "It will not be easy for them to handle the situation at this stage:…"
>
> "RT @ReutersLobby: It will not be easy for them to handle the situation at this stage:…"

As the above tweet and retweet shows that "RT @ReutresLobby:" is extra in retweet. So the above code will not remove this retweet from the final set. I want to remove all such tweets that are a copy of a another tweet because the focus is on text of the tweet and creation time and not on other fields.
I tried to search for it but could not find anything related on the forum.I hope someone will help me out with this problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a pretty quick fix:

```
import csv
import re

csvInputFile = open('inputFile.csv', 'r',encoding="utf-8", newline='')
csvOutputFile = open('outputFile.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline='')

csvReader = csv.reader(csvInputFile)
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvOutputFile)
cleanData = set()

for row in csvReader:
    #print(row[3])
    if row[3] in cleanData or re.sub('^RT @.*: ', '', row[3]) in cleanData:
        continue
    cleanData.add(row[3])
    csvWriter.writerow(row)

print(cleanData)
csvOutputFile.close()
csvInputFile.close()
```

The condition I added sees if the tweet, when stripped of the retweet prefix, exists already in the cleaned set.

Comment: Thank you Will for your answer. Its giving an error for a missing positional string in sub: TypeError: sub() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Comment: See the edit to the post. In my initial response, I did miss the third argument to `sub`, which should be `row[3]`

Comment: yes i already added the the important string argument by looking the argument details of the sub fucntion. Thanks a lot mate for your answer :)

Comment: Well now it works pretty fine. Just in order to learn alternatives, i was also thinking about using "SequenceMatcher(None, string1,string2).ratio()"  as i believe it might work as well...

Comment: Also i tested it on just around 100 tweets. I hope that it will also work for very large data sets. As sometimes these data sets are very un-predictive :).

Comment: If this is working for you, please accept so others can find the solution :)